# Calendar not showing up in Bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am implementing bootstrap datetimepicker with below code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have included below scripts and styles:
[image: Files included]

And my output is looking like below:
[image: Output on page]

Order of including files is:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/Styles/PreLayout.css")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/moment")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/JavaScripts/PreLayout.js")
```

When I click on calendar icon nothing happens. What mistake I am making in implementation?

EDIT:

Added fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/1c1nr9sp/4/

Comment: did you add bootstrap datepicker js file ? and add reference?

Comment: It really be really helpful to provide a working example for people (such as a snippet or fiddle), so it's easy for us to see and fix your problem. Otherwise we would have to setup the entire environment and get the libraries ourselves to make sure our solution works, in which most people would rather not take time to do. [Making a easily reproducible example can greatly help getting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ZohaibWaqar I have added bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js.

Comment: run your application and when page load press f12 and goto Console and then check error. and then click on calender and again check the error and let me know///

Comment: @ZohaibWaqar I don't see any error in either of actions(loading and click) but still it does not work.

Comment: @ATP, the cause of the issue is, the references should be placed in correct order. See the answer I've provided.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The cause of your issue is, you did not place the reference scripts in correct order.

See the documentation: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Vimalan. I replaced my bootstrap datetime js and css with that in your answer's link and it worked. Now I can see calendar. But still I find the selector distorted as given in snapshot in my question. Can you please suggest the reason for that too?

Comment: @ATP, I am not able to reproduce the selector distorted issue... one reason could be, the .form-control css could be overridden somewhere in your other css files... It will be helpful if you could update the fiddler which reflects the issue?

Comment: Even I can't reproduce that in fiddler. Seems like some local system issue. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: I also had a problem with the files I'd pulled from bower.
Something was silently failing. Replaced my references with what you have and it now works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the messed up spacing between the textbox and calendar icon, I was able to fix that by commenting out the line:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

My project handles this for me instead. ASP.net/MVC
I also changed the col-sm-6 to col-sm-12.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems using **jQuery 3.x**. (latest version of Bootstrap 3 supports jQuery 3).  The dropdown would partially render but without the calendar.  The time picker portion worked ok.

Downgrading to **jQuery 2.x** fixed the problem.

Comment: So there's no hope of making it work with jQuery 3.x? I had to upgrade jQuery for using another library and this happened...

Comment: @mrrrk Please check your css file once. I was facing same issue. For me, it was display: none.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check what icon-set are you using.
There are multiple font icon sets like `Font Awesome`, `Material Design`, `Bootstrap glyphicons`, etc.

By default `DateTimePicker` uses `Bootstrap glyphicons` but you can specify your custom icons for all other things.

```
icons:{
            time: 'glyphicon glyphicon-time',
            date: 'glyphicon glyphicon-calendar',
            up: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up',
            down: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down',
            previous: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left',
            next: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right',
            today: 'glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot',
            clear: 'glyphicon glyphicon-trash',
            close: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove'
        }
```

Ref- http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#icons

Answer (score 0):

## Similar problem but different solution

It's specific to ASP.NET Core projects. In default visual studio template,
all input tags are set with a max width of 280px like this:

**file:** *site.css*

```
/* Set widths on the form inputs since otherwise they're 100% wide */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Just remove that and the calendar icon fits in the right place :)