# Icons of datetimepicker not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I use bootstrap 4,fontawesome v5.7 and this plugin https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Usage/

The calendar its working but my probleme is the icons is not showing

Look this screen:

[image]

Comment: is there any err in console

Comment: ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601942/calendar-not-showing-up-in-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: Someone else brought up this issue in Github, so maybe this will help:  https://github.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/issues/127

Answer (score 8):

The Following code solved my issue.

```
$.fn.datetimepicker.Constructor.Default = $.extend({},
            $.fn.datetimepicker.Constructor.Default,
            { icons:
                    { time: 'fas fa-clock',
                        date: 'fas fa-calendar',
                        up: 'fas fa-arrow-up',
                        down: 'fas fa-arrow-down',
                        previous: 'fas fa-arrow-circle-left',
                        next: 'fas fa-arrow-circle-right',
                        today: 'far fa-calendar-check-o',
                        clear: 'fas fa-trash',
                        close: 'far fa-times' } });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 answer completed with result in image, but please avoid answer code with images. In the official doc suggest do it before the init.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Version 5.8 of font awesome and having this issue. Changing

```
fa-clock-o
```

to

```
fa-clock
```

within the following file fixed it for me -

```
tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js
```

Looks as though FontAwesome has changed the name of the clock icon in version 5.

Answer (score 0):

Information about this can be found in the official doc: https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Options/

> Global defaults can be get/set by
> $.fn.datetimepicker.Constructor.Default
>
> e.g. To set icons to use Font Awesome 5
>
> ```
> $.fn.datetimepicker.Constructor.Default = $.extend({}, $.fn.datetimepicker.Constructor.Default, {
>             icons: {
>                 time: 'far fa-clock',
>                 date: 'far fa-calendar',
>                 up: 'far fa-arrow-up',
>                 down: 'far fa-arrow-down',
>                 previous: 'far fa-chevron-left',
>                 next: 'far fa-chevron-right',
>                 today: 'far fa-calendar-check-o',
>                 clear: 'far fa-trash',
>                 close: 'far fa-times'
>             } });
> ```
>
> Do this before you init pickers.

Also in the official doc:
https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Usage/#custom-icons

**Custom Icons**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker9" data-target-input="nearest">
                <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker9"/>
                <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker9" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker9').datetimepicker({
                icons: {
                    time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                    date: "fa fa-calendar",
                    up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
                    down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```