# Datetimepicker showing only time option

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker library to use calendar to select date. Now, due to requirement change, I need to also select time along with date.

Before new change, I was using below code to show calendar on text field:

```
<script>
     $('#my-datetime-field').datetimepicker({format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'});
</script>
```

With above code, calendar is showing properly and things are working fine.

To show, time option too, I have just changed the format like below:

```
<script>
     $('#my-datetime-field').datetimepicker({format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'});
</script>
```

But using this way, only time option is showing, calendar is not showing. Look at my attached screenshot:

[Click here to see issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zurKo.png)

I am using below library to use calendar:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js

Can someone please look at this and let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: There's a SO question here where somebody is having the same (or similar) issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601942/calendar-not-showing-up-in-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/) state it

> Takes a [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) format string

So in your case I *think* it should be:
`{format: 'DD-MM-YYYY, HH:mm:ss'}` (note the comma)

Comment: Thanks for reply but it is not working. I have edited my question and attached the screenshot. Please look at that. You will understand clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Set type="datetime-local" for the input statement.